# Flushing all session variables while keeping user logged in - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How could I keep a user logged in when trying to destroy a cart session when they complete an order?

I am trying to flush a cart session whenever a user completes an order on my site, when the order is complete the user is redirected but the items in their cart are still there, is there anyway to delete them and keep the user logged in?

I store my session like so

```
$cart = session()->get('cart');

        // if cart is empty then this will be the first product
        if (!$cart) {


            $cart = [
                $id => [
                    "id" => $product->id,
                    "name" => $product->name,
                    "quantity" => 1,
                    "price" => $product->unit_price
                ]
            ];

            session()->put('cart', $cart);

            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
        }
```

And trying to delete it like so

```
$cart = session()->get('cart');


            if (isset($cart[$request->id])) {

                unset($cart[$request->id]);

                session()->put('cart', $cart);
            }

            session()->flash('success', 'Order Fulfilled');


        return redirect("/");
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using `$request->session()->flush();` then it will flush or destroy your whole data.

Try to use `$request->session()->forget('key');`. Just pass the Key in Forget Method. Which will remove only Session data belongs to that Key.

Comment: Great, thanks for that it worked when i passed my variable through!

Comment: Yeah, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

When I update my refresh function to this below, the session restarts

```
        $request->session()->forget('cart');

        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        if (!$cart) {
            session()->put('cart', []);
        }

        return redirect("/");
```